# Print lines of a compressed gz file based on another index file

Tags: bash, performance, unix, awk

Need to print specific lines of a large txt.gz file, using an index file

Hi all,

I found several examples for printing specific lines of a non-compressed files but could not find any solution for a very large gz file.

My index file (idx.txt) looks like this, and contains 700,000 indices:

```
1745  
1746  
7379  
13920  
13921  
16681  
16682
...
...
...
54830241
54867703
54867710
```

I would like to retrieve all these 700,000 lines in my other source file, which is a very large compressed CSV file with 55,000,000 rows and looks like this:

```
100035243,2,"Chronic obstructive pulmonary disease","SS","LETAIRIS","AMBRISENTAN","","Dyspnoea",NA,73,"F","","","CN"
100035672,1,"Myeloproliferative disorder","PS","JAKAFI","RUXOLITINIB","ORAL","Platelet count increased",20131206,48.501,"F","79.37","KG","OT"
100035914,1,"Multiple sclerosis","PS","GILENYA","FINGOLIMOD HYDROCHLORIDE","ORAL","Lymphocyte count decreased",20130718,47.154,"F","","","OT"
....
```

What I tried so far:

```
sed -nf idx.txt <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz) > output.txt  
awk 'NR==FNR{i[$0];next}i[FNR]' idx.txt <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz) > output.txt
```

Both are very slow.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the time purely to decompress your file? That will set the lower bound on your overall time anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO your `awk` code looks ok to me so there could be 1 way to increase its speed of processing. Though I am not sure(and since your samples are not clear so didn't test also), if your id.txt file's last entry is far lesser than total number of lines in .gz file then you could actually exit from `awk` code and NO need to read Input_files, try it out once.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{i[$0]=$0;last=$0;next} i[FNR]{print} FNR!=NR && FNR>last{exit}' idx.txt <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz) > output.txt
```

So what I am doing is, I am creating a variable named `last` here whose value should be last line value of `ids.txt`.Then in 2nd condition I am checking if line number is greater than value of last entry in `ids.txt` then exit from code.

***EDIT:*** Changed OP's code ***from*** `i[$0]` ***to*** `i[$0]=$0` in first condition since condition `i[FNR]` will only work when array i is having values. Changed it after user mentioned in comments.

***PS:*** This will definitely save time only and only in case you have huge difference between last line value of ids.txt and total number of lines present in .gz file. Since I am going with your statement that you have very huge data.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder, the command runs smoothly for 30 seconds or so, however the output is empty. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnCena, I added a bit of code now, check now and let me know?

Comment: still no success - runs a bit longer but returns empty file.

Comment: @JohnCena, ok not sure,try now once?

Comment: No cigar yet. I assume it has nothing to do with the fact that the compressed file is in CSV format?

Comment: @JohnCena, ok do 1 thing, run it without using output file like `awk 'NR==FNR{i[$0];last=$0;next} i[FNR]{print} FNR!=NR && FNR>last{exit}' idx.txt <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz)` and let me know then?

Comment: @JohnCena, hmmm, check if you have spaces at last of `ids.txt` by any chance? by doing `cat -e ids.txt once and let me know then?

Comment: '$' at the end of each line.

Comment: @JohnCena, ok 1 more try, `awk 'NR==FNR{i[$0]=$0;last=$0;next} i[FNR]{print} FNR!=NR && FNR>last{exit}' idx.txt <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz)` Let me know then?  I am pretty sure this should work.

Comment: Incredible! This version works in 60 seconds! Many thanks.

Comment: @JohnCena, yesssss I knew it, it is going to help you. I am very happy that it helped you :)  Also you could try to give up-vote for people's helpful answers, happy learning and keep posting good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Both `sed` and  `awk` solutions looks good. Probably, `sed` one is faster than `awk` one. And probably they are the faster things you can get. To reduce time... reduce the input file size.

One extra thing you can do is to stop reading after last line printed, so if you know that last line printed will be far away from the end of file, you can avoid a lengthy decompression:

```
sed -nf idx.txt <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz | head -n "$(sort -nr idx.txt | head -1)") > output.txt
```

Comment: your solution is good, even I too thought the same but then thought may be OP don't want to extract the file. I believe my solution could be(guessing) faster than OP's actual command but let's see how it goes.

Comment: Both solutions are good. Mine is not assuming that the IDs file is sorted, but is quite equivalent to yours. But they will only be faster if the last index is away from the end. If it is near the end, it won't make difference. Or it will even be slower, due to the extra commands added. My feeling is that it is a general case and will only make a small difference on the long run.

Comment: Thanks @Poshi, but I'm getting this error: "sed: 1: idx.txt: command expected"

Comment: Well... I believed you when you said that your sed command worked. My update to your command does not affect the point of your new failure.

Comment: Try with: `sed -nf <(sed 's/$/p/' idx.txt) <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz | head -n "$(sort -nr idx.txt | head -1)") > output.txt`

Comment: @Poshi indeed my original sed command was wrong. However it seems that the performance is similarly slow to that without your suggestion to stop reading after last line printed, i.e. just using <(gzip -dc gzfile.gz)

Comment: If performance is similar, then your time-black hole is on the file descompression itself. Best things you can do are reduce file size, get faster disk or get faster processor (it depends on where is your bottleneck).